# Including a uri "/user/sidebar" page (Kohana Framework) in PHP

Tags: php, kohana

I would like to have the page on user/sidebar on the right in the template design.

Normally, I would include a php file. But I am using Kohana Framework so I have created a view and a controller for this sidebar, and exists on mysite.com/user/sidebar

Now how would i `<?php include "/user/sidebar"; ?>` correct? I get no such file og dir error for this. I tried full url, but allow_url_include=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just looking through the Kohana documentation...

It seems like you can include a "request" inside a view with the following command.

`<?php echo Request::factory('user/sidebar')->execute() ?>`

See this page for more info: http://kohanaframework.org/3.0/guide/kohana/mvc/views

Answer (score 0):

AndrewR's comment is close.  For Kohana 3.2, you'll want to load a view within a view and not a request within a view:

```
<?php echo View::factory('/user/sidebar'); ?>
```

or

```
<?php include Kohana::find_file('views', 'user/sidebar') ?>
```

Either is acceptable to do.

Comment: He's answer was right, because by only including the view it did not include the related controller with it.